# How can I use multiple toolchains in a CMake buildsystem configuration?

Tags: cmake

I have two toolchain.cmake files for different architectures. Is there any way to invoke both in CMakeLists.txt file or i have to invoke them respectively as I do as usual. Then it works nicely. My files i.e
toolchain_a.cmake and toolchain_b.cmake

I tried to do in if statements and with `OSX_ARCHITECTURES` variable but did not work as I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a `CMakeLists.txt` including the `ExternalProject` module adding two projects. One for each toolchain.

All of this could be done from  a single `CMakeLists.txt` using the "SuperBuild" paradigm.

In a nutshell, it works like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Awesome)
option(Awesome_SUPERBUILD "Cross-compile Awesome for each toolchain" ON)
include(ExternalProject)
if(Awesome_SUPERBUILD)
  ExternalProject_Add(Awesome-ToolchainA
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ToolchainA-build
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain_a.cmake
      -DAwesome_SUPERBUILD:BOOL=0
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
  ExternalProject_Add(Awesome-ToolchainB
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ToolchainB-build
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/toolchain_b.cmake
      -DAwesome_SUPERBUILD:BOOL=0
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
  return()
endif()

# Below is the CMake code of the project to cross-compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolchain things are supposed to be the same throughout a single CMake buildsystem configuration- except for [external projects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). For example, [the docs for `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) say:

> This is the command that will be used as the `<LANG>` compiler. Once set, you can not change this variable.

Also see https://discourse.cmake.org/t/using-multiple-toolchains-in-the-same-project/1505/2?u=starball, where Ben Boeckel (a CMake maintainer) commented:

> CMake does not support more than one toolchain per language. It’s just a fundamental design decision baked in at the very early days that isn’t possible to feasibly fix today.
>
> The typical fix is to build the project twice (via ExternalProject), once for the host and then for the cross-compilation step. You can see this in VTK’s [iOS](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/CMake/vtkiOS.cmake) and [Android](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/CMake/vtkAndroid.cmake) build setups.

I defer to [J-Christophe's answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453860/11107541) on how you could do that.